Publish ArcGIS Feature Service layers in GeoServer
Is it possible to publish layers from ArcGIS REST Service (ArcGIS FeatureServer) in GeoServer? If this service is not available as WMTS.
Example: https://services2.arcgis.com/ZASkNq1SMoPvFBOv/arcgis/rest/services/Roads_Consolidated_AGOL_view/FeatureServer
It's easy to add layers from such services to QGIS, but in the case of GeoServer I can't find any information.

So you want a server to publish a different server's services? Isn't that like walking into a Burger King and asking for a BigMac?

Its not possible to publish ESRI Rest service in Geoserver. They are two different systems.
The QGIS can consume WMS services that are served from Geoserver or ESRI with no issue, if that's what you are asking?
https://www.lifeingis.com/adding-layers-from-geoserver-in-qgis/#:~:text=The%20three%20formats%20of%20data,from%20the%20Manage%20layers%20toolbar.

Thanks @Vince - your answer is thought-provoking ;)
